# HTML/CSS Lay Out Issues with Positions

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to redesign a website that was created a few years ago for the company i work for. Usually i don't have trouble with re-designing a website with existing HTML/CSS. But today i'm having a little trouble. Maybe i just need more coffee, but here is my issue.

I'm trying to have the #CSSmenu float left, and the .promo and .quote to float right. It seems that the `#CSSmenu` is stopping them from floating to the right. They are being forced to the bottom of the div as if the `#CSSmenu` has a total width that takes up the entire wrapper which is `950px`.

I attached a mock up to better explain what i'm trying to-do as well as the code. I have a feeling that it's somewhere in the CSS that's doing this, but being that i did not design the site prior to now i'm having a little trouble finding it without comments.

http://postimg.org/image/ypwpe0fpl/

```
 <div class="content_width"> <!-- Control Width of wrapper for content -->


        <div id='cssmenu'> <!-- Containter For Nav Menu -->
    <ul>
       <li>Browse Our Products</li> <!--List Title-->

       <li><a href='#'>Business Cards</a></li>
       <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'>Stationary</a>
            <ul>
             <li class=''><a href='#'>Letter Head</a></li>
             <li class=''><a href='#'>Envelopes</a></li>
             <li class=''><a href='#'>Labels</a></li>
             <li class=''><a href='#'>Note Pads</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
       <li><a href='#'>Brochures</a></li>

       <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'>Signage</a>
            <ul>
             <li class=''><a href='#'>Signs</a></li>
             <li class=''><a href='#'>Yard signs</a></li>
             <li class=''><a href='#'>Trade Show Graphics</a></li>
             <li class=''><a href='#'>X-Frame With Banners</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
       <li><a href='#'>Post Cards</a></li>
       <li><a href='#'>Vinyl Banners</a></li>

       <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'>Mailing Services</a>
            <ul>
             <li class=''><a href='#'>Ink Jet</a></li>
             <li class=''><a href='#'>Direct Mailing</a></li>
             <li class=''><a href='#'>Sorting & Tabbing</a></li>
             <li class=''><a href='#'>Mailing List</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

       <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'>Marketing Material</a>
            <ul>
             <li class=''><a href='#'>Greeting Cards</a></li>
             <li class=''><a href='#'>Rock Cards</a></li>
             <li class=''><a href='#'>Brochures</a></li>
             <li class=''><a href='#'>Book Marks</a></li>
             <li class=''><a href='#'>Presentation Folders</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
       <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'>Speciality Products</a>
            <ul>
             <li class=''><a href='#'>Magnets</a></li>
             <li class=''><a href='#'>T-Shirts (Heat Transfer Imaging)</a></li>
             <li class=''><a href='#'>Bumper Stickers</a></li>
             <li class=''><a href='#'>Plastic</a></li>
             <li class=''><a href='#'>Static Cling</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
       <li><a href='#'>Apparel</a>  </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="promo">
      Promo 1
    </div>

    <div class="quote">
    Quote 1
    </div>


    </div><!-- End of Content Wrapper -->

    </div> <!-- End of CSS Menu-->


<style>
/* Added CSS by Darius Shojaei for Content Body */

#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  width: 180px;
  background: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 12px 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #666666;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #222222;
}
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  content: "";
  border-radius: 2px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a::after {
  top: 14px;
  background: #666666;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a::after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:hover::after {
  background: #222222;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  top: 13px;
  background: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover > a::after,
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:hover::after {
  background: #dddddd;
}
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a::before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  content: "";
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a::before {
  top: 16px;
  border-left-color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::before {
  top: 15px;
  border-left-color: #2e353b;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  -webkit-perspective: 600px;
  -moz-perspective: 600px;
  perspective: 600px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -9999px;
  width: 180px;
  background: #2e353b;
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease, -moz-transform 0.2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease, -webkit-transform 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s ease, -ms-transform 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease, -o-transform 0.2s ease;
  transition: opacity .2s ease, transform .2s ease;
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 45deg);
  transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul {
  left: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
#cssmenu ul ul::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: -8px;
  top: 14px;
  z-index: 5;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right-color: #2e353b;
  content: "";
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
  padding: 12px 15px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #dddddd;
}  

/* End of CSS Vertical Nav Menu */

.promo {
    width:355px;
    background-color:#F0F;
    display:inline;
    float:right;

}
.quote {
    width:355px;
    background-color:#F0F;
    display:inline;
    float:right;

}

.content_width, .content_width_wrapper {
    width: 950px;

    /* Do Not Change This */
    margin: 0px auto;
}





/* end of new CSS */
</style>
```

Comment: Instead of the floats take a look at the features of the (almost) new **flexbox** element: it will save you some layout annoyances.

Comment: Are you actually floating #CSSMenu to the left? I'm not seeing that anywhere in your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you've placed the two things you wanted to float right (.promo and .quote) into the thing that you want to float left, #CSSMenu. This just floats .promo and .quote to the right **within** the #CSSMenu container. You need to remove them from #CSSMenu, and then float #CSSMenu left.

[Here's a working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0roqxnbo/).

Updated code:

```
    <div id='cssmenu'> <!-- Containter For Nav Menu -->
<ul>
   <li>Browse Our Products</li> <!--List Title-->

   <li><a href='#'>Business Cards</a></li>
   <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'>Stationary</a>
        <ul>
         <li class=''><a href='#'>Letter Head</a></li>
         <li class=''><a href='#'>Envelopes</a></li>
         <li class=''><a href='#'>Labels</a></li>
         <li class=''><a href='#'>Note Pads</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
   <li><a href='#'>Brochures</a></li>

   <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'>Signage</a>
        <ul>
         <li class=''><a href='#'>Signs</a></li>
         <li class=''><a href='#'>Yard signs</a></li>
         <li class=''><a href='#'>Trade Show Graphics</a></li>
         <li class=''><a href='#'>X-Frame With Banners</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
   <li><a href='#'>Post Cards</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Vinyl Banners</a></li>

   <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'>Mailing Services</a>
        <ul>
         <li class=''><a href='#'>Ink Jet</a></li>
         <li class=''><a href='#'>Direct Mailing</a></li>
         <li class=''><a href='#'>Sorting & Tabbing</a></li>
         <li class=''><a href='#'>Mailing List</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

   <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'>Marketing Material</a>
        <ul>
         <li class=''><a href='#'>Greeting Cards</a></li>
         <li class=''><a href='#'>Rock Cards</a></li>
         <li class=''><a href='#'>Brochures</a></li>
         <li class=''><a href='#'>Book Marks</a></li>
         <li class=''><a href='#'>Presentation Folders</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
   <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'>Speciality Products</a>
        <ul>
         <li class=''><a href='#'>Magnets</a></li>
         <li class=''><a href='#'>T-Shirts (Heat Transfer Imaging)</a></li>
         <li class=''><a href='#'>Bumper Stickers</a></li>
         <li class=''><a href='#'>Plastic</a></li>
         <li class=''><a href='#'>Static Cling</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
   <li><a href='#'>Apparel</a>  </li>
</ul>


</div><!-- End of CSS Menu -->
<div class="promo">
  Promo 1
</div>

<div class="quote">
Quote 1
</div>
</div> <!-- End of Content Wrapper-->
```

CSS:

```
#cssmenu {
    float:left;
}
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  width: 180px;
  background: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 12px 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #666666;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #222222;
}
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  content: "";
  border-radius: 2px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a::after {
  top: 14px;
  background: #666666;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a::after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:hover::after {
  background: #222222;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  top: 13px;
  background: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover > a::after,
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:hover::after {
  background: #dddddd;
}
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a::before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  content: "";
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a::before {
  top: 16px;
  border-left-color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::before {
  top: 15px;
  border-left-color: #2e353b;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  -webkit-perspective: 600px;
  -moz-perspective: 600px;
  perspective: 600px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -9999px;
  width: 180px;
  background: #2e353b;
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease, -moz-transform 0.2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease, -webkit-transform 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s ease, -ms-transform 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease, -o-transform 0.2s ease;
  transition: opacity .2s ease, transform .2s ease;
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 45deg);
  transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul {
  left: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
#cssmenu ul ul::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: -8px;
  top: 14px;
  z-index: 5;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right-color: #2e353b;
  content: "";
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
  padding: 12px 15px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #dddddd;
}  

/* End of CSS Vertical Nav Menu */

.promo {
    width:355px;
    background-color:#F0F;
    display:inline;
    float:right;

}
.quote {
    width:355px;
    background-color:#F0F;
    display:inline;
    float:right;

}

.content_width, .content_width_wrapper {
    width: 950px;

    /* Do Not Change This */
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much. I actually knew that was what was happening but for some reason yesterday i could not find where the container for the css menu was ending. Thank you for using your eyes to find the error. This fix is much better than trying to cheat by using absolute positioning or fixed position. Thanks again.

Comment: @DariusShojaei no problem! please mark my answer as correct if this solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to "float" in a set position on the page no matter what, try

```
position:fixed;
top:somepixels;
left:somepixels;
etc
```